# Trying to use ProcessBuilder in Java to give input to shell script during execution

Tags: java, bash, shell, sh

I am trying to execute a shell script that takes input with Java.

Here is my code so far...

```
    OutputStreamWriter output;

    Process p = new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{"sh", "-c", "/data1/Abhishek/hello.sh"}).start();
    output = new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream());
    String line = "";
    String text = "";
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
         if(line.equals("Enter Your Name: ")) {
                String password = "password";
                output.write(password);
                output.write('\n');
                output.flush();
         }
         text += line;
         text += "\n";
    }
    input.close();
    try {
        p.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
    }
```

Here is the shell script..

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter Your Name: "  username
echo "Welcome $username!"
```

However it is not working. The script is still waiting for the input...
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't use `readLine()` because the script doesn't write a line. It just writes some characters without a newline so that you can respond on the same line. The easiest fix is probably to change your script to write a complete line with `echo` instead of using `read -p`

Comment: @thatotherguy I'll try that, is the way to give input through outputStreamWriter correct?

Comment: @thatotherguy I got it working with your fix. But how would I approach it if I had to give input in the same line?

Comment: You would need to redefine what you read from "a line" to something else. Maybe you would read until a timeout, or until you match your string, or until a colon. It's a fragile and error prone problem which is why people only use this kind of integration as a last resort.

Comment: @otherguy Thank you, your solution worked for me :)